# Extract Row from Spreadsheet if Not Blank According to Month

Tags: vba, excel

I've been having trouble coming up with a formula that can extract and entire row if Not Blank and if the Month Matches.

WorkSheet1 - Outputs:

[image: WorkSheet1 - Outputs]

Worksheet2 - Inputs:

[image: Worksheet2 - Inputs]

In Worksheet2 - Inputs, each month is a column heading. In the cells below, some are empty some are not.

I need to find a way to copy the row of each cell that is Not Empty and paste it into the Output Worksheet in the Corresponding month cell.

Update:

Sorry I should have been more specific, On the Output Page, these is an area for the user to specify specific months. (ie User might input July to September, in this case, i would only need to look between July August and September)

I would share the macros I've tried using before, but its mostly gibberish..

Comment: That looks like a reasonable statement of the problem. We like to see people's efforts here as well, would you edit that into your question, at the end? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't just copy ALL cells over. Why is it a problem if it copies a "blank" cell? It'll still be blank on your output sheet.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific, On the Output Page, these is an area for the user to specify specific months. (ie User might input July to September, in this case, i would only need to look between July August and September)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your table start with "A1" [row1 - date headers], here is the code:

```
Sub CleanData()
Dim arr() As Variant
Dim sh As Worksheet
lastcolumn = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & 1).End(xlToRight).Column
tableHeight = Range(Columns(1), Columns(lastcolumn)).Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row


For i = 1 To lastcolumn
    y = 0
    For j = 1 To tableHeight
        If Cells(j, i) <> "" Then
           If longestcolumn <= y Then
                ReDim Preserve arr(lastcolumn - 1, y)
                arr(i - 1, y) = Cells(j, i)
                If j = 1 Then arr(i - 1, y) = MonthName(Month(Cells(j, i)))
                longestcolumn = y
                y = y + 1
            Else
                arr(i - 1, y) = Cells(j, i)
                If j = 1 Then arr(i - 1, y) = MonthName(Month(Cells(j, i)))
                y = y + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
             ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
sh.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(longestcolumn, lastcolumn)) = Application.Transpose(arr)

End Sub
```

*Edited tableHeight parameter equation*

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment about the output page having an area that specifies the months feed that in and this should get what you want. `CopyNonEmtpyRowsOver` takes in the range that includes the information you want, as well as your destination sheet. If your requirements change and you need a different output sheet or the source of your information changes you can change them where the subs are called to be clearer about your intent.

```
Public Sub RowCopyProcedure()
    'Edit the argument of sourceRange determine your limits
    CopyNonEmtpyRowsOver Range(Sheet2.Cells(1, 1), Sheet2.Cells(11, "I")), Sheet1
End Sub

Private Sub CopyNonEmtpyRowsOver(ByVal sourceRange As Range, ByVal destinationSheet As Worksheet)

    Dim rowToMigrate As Range
    Dim populatedRows As Long
    Dim isRowPopulated As Boolean
    For Each rowToMigrate In sourceRange.Rows
        On Error Resume Next
            isRowPopulated = rowToMigrate.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count > 0
        On Error GoTo 0
        If isRowPopulated Then
            MigrateRowOver rowToMigrate, destinationSheet.Cells(populatedRows + 1, 1)
            populatedRows = populatedRows + 1
            isRowPopulated = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub MigrateRowOver(ByVal sourceRow As Range, ByVal destinationCell As Range)
    sourceRow.Copy destinationCell.Resize(ColumnSize:=sourceRow.Columns.Count)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you IvenBach, I will be trying out this code this weekend, I will let you know my results. Much Appreciated.